# How to troubleshoot HTTP 404 and 500 errors on Google App Engine?

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

Is there an effective way to troubleshoot a server configuration for a PHP application on Google Cloud?

I gave it a try with a Laravel application and keep hitting 404 or 500 HTTP errors when deploying on GAE.  Same project is working great on my local server.

Is there any effective way of troubleshooting through error_logs for 500?
Any complete documentation on how to structure the yaml file to prevent this?  Google's documentation is incomplete and outdated and still refers to old runtimes.

Here is my current file :

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# required on some platforms so ".env" is not skipped
skip_files: false

env_variables:
  # The values here will override those in ".env". This is useful for
  # production-specific configuration. However, feel free to set these
  # values in ".env" instead if you prefer.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

The google cloud console has a decent log viewer that will show you all your 500's with as much detail as possible as to the cause. You would need to share some of the 500 logs to allow anyone to help you solve them here.
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: I appreciate your answer Matt, but logs were empty.  i think the problem occured before it actually hits the webserver and PHP.  Seems like a deployment issue.

I also noticed many problems with Google's solution, first being no decent support for PHP7.

Got tired of it and went for AWS and everything went smoothly from there.

Thanks again.